# PHP array generation

Tags: php, arrays, json

iam sending some data through ajax using  **$("#pax_datas").serializeArray()** and when i receive it in the backend PHP array is coming like below format.

```html
Array
(
    [product_id] => 1836
    [set_product_date] => 2019-12-29
    [first_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => somen
        )

    [last_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Doe
            [1] => ram
        )

    [email] => Array
        (
            [0] => xyz@gmail.com
            [1] => lmn@gmail.com
        )

)
```

I need to construct that array and json encode so that i need the above array data to be constructed like the below format

```html
"data": [
   {
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Doe",
   "email":"xyz@gmail.com",
  },
  {
   "firstName": "Somen",
   "lastName": "ram",
   "email": "lmn@gmail.com",
  }
    ],
```

Comment: $myJSON = json_encode($myObj) . Here $myObj is the php array

Comment: no first i need to group users and then only i can use json _encode, i am not able to group user data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over one of the `first_name`, `last_name` or `email` keys of the array, using the keys of that array to index into the other two:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($array['first_name'] as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = array('first_name' => $value, 
                    'last_name' => $array['last_name'][$key],
                    'email' => $array['email'][$key]);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "somen",
        "last_name": "ram",
        "email": "lmn@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/AivXk)